# JPA using one join table for two OneToMany entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

There's an Entity Class 'A' (supposed to be a Person),There's another Entity Class 'B' (supposed to be a Contract).

Entity 'A' has a relation `@OneToMany` to Class 'B' ( a person can sign alot of contracts). Entity 'B' also has a relation `@OneToMany` to Class 'A' (a contract can have many person signing it).

In this case, there's gonna be 2 `JoinTable` in database, but actually they both are somehow the same.

Is there anyway that i make them just using One JoinTable?

tnx for any help!

Comment: Aren't you describing a @ManyToMany relation?

Comment: OneToMany does not require any JoinTable. Only for a ManyToMany you need one JoinTable. Why do you think you need 2 JoinTables?

Comment: yes it's a @MTM relation.

Comment: @tak3shi , but it makes anyway a join table in my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a @ManyToMany relation to me...

**in class Person**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="PERS_CONTRACTS")
public Set<Contract> getContracts() { return contracts; }
```

**in class Contract**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="contracts")
public Set<Person> getSigners() { return signers; }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there anyway to combine 2 OneToMany to each other, like my Question, instead of MTM relation using 2 OTM but with 1 Join table, i know it makes no sense but is there maybe a way or an idea about that?

Comment: Why whould you want to do that, @RezaPayambari? If you really want to use 2 OTM relations, you could create an entity called something like 'PersonContract' which represents a table in the db, and which has a OTM relation with Person and with Contract. (One person can have a lot of PersonContracts and one contract can also have a lot of PersonContracts)

Answer (score 1):

By using two @OneToMany there is no JoinTable. 
you can use @ManyToMany like this

```
@ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(
      name="AB",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
  private List<B> bS;
```

Comment: It is possible - allthough not common at all - to use a JoinTable for a @OneToMany relation

Answer (score 1):

Its a kind of Many to Many relationships. So it need just one junction table like person_contract in database. It will contains columns like:

1. Person_id
2. Contract_id

where both person_id & contract_id will be a composite unique key.

In hibernate it will be:
1. In Person table

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "person_contract ", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id",
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Contract> contracts;
```

2. In Contract table

   `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "contracts")
   public Set<Person> persons;`

Answer (score 1):

**Situation:**

You are complicating things here, the appropriate relationship between your Entities would be `ManyToMany`, because :

- A `person` *can sign many* `contracts`.
- And a `contract` *can be signed by many* `persons`.

And one `JoinTable` in this relationship is sufficient to give you all the requested details:

- Who signed a given `Contract`.
- Which `Contracts` have a `Person` signed.

**Mapping:**

So your mapping will be like this:

In your `Person` class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons")
private Set<Contract> contracts= new HashSet<Contract>();
```

And in your `Contract` class:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "PERSONS_CONTRACTS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACT_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
)
private Set<Person> persons= new HashSet<Person>();
```

You can check this [**Hibernate Many-to-Many Association Annotations Example**](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-annotations-example) for further details.

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there anyway to combine 2 OneToMany to each other, like my Question, instead of MTM relation using 2 OTM but with 1 Join table, i know it makes no sense but is there maybe a way or an idea about that?

Comment: @RezaPayambari I think it's possible to have two relationships between both entities (I have never tried it my self), but it won't be much useful and illogical. But you can have in each Entity a `Set` of the other entity and an `instance of it. For example in your Person class you can have both `Set<Contract> contracts;` and `Contract contract`, and then adjust the mapping to map each one accordingly. You have to try it. **But `ManyToMany` here is really sufficient and  answers your question.**

Comment: hey, thanks for your tips.'ManyToMany' helped me in that case but I needed to do it with 'OneToMany'.